# Regex para obtenção de Token - Zabbix

Tags: regex, api, token, zabbix

Estou tentando coletar dois conjuntos de caracteres em um `token` de autenticação. A intenção é que o `regex` colete a palavra `bearer` e o resultado do `access_token`.

Estou com dificuldades para unir ambas coletas.

É possível realizar as duas coletar em um mesmo regex?

Token abaixo - Imagem e texto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
{
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "refresh_token": "MjUwMDAwMTJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIzNTMxMzI1MDAwMDE2NiIsImlhdCI6MTYxMjUzMjE2NSwibmJmIjoxNjEyNTMyMTY1LCJleHAiOjE2MTI1MzU3NjUsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6Im1vYmlsZUZpcnN0RGF0YSIsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6IjM1MzEzMjUwMDAwMTY2IiwiaW5zdGl0dXRpb24iOiIwMDAwMDAwMyIsImVzdGFibGleyJ0eXAiOijpbIjg5NDUwNDIzIl0sImRldmljZSI6IlBvc3RtYW4iLCJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsIm9yaWdpbl9wb3MiOmZhbHNlfQ.CEwEPwRXNN0OrcYk7rc2FFzPwMGPhOKnjUUfuR97bN7hfmwEMp_dQQ4mLRod4xuv32xlEFLPvmxtiM-9IiA53w",
  "refresh_expires_in": 3600,
  "expires_in": 900,
  "access_token": "osjjjjsssjJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIzNTMxMzI1MDAwMDE2NiIsImlhdCI6MTYxMjUzMjE2NSwibmJmIjoxNjEyNTMyMTY1LCJleHAiOjE2MTI1MzMwNjUsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6Im1vYmlsZUZpcnN0RGF0YSIsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6IjM1MzEzMjeyJ0eXAiOiIiwiaW5zdGl0dXRpb24iOiIwMDAwMDAwMyIsImVzdGFibGlzaG1lbnRzIjpbIjg5NDUwNDIzIl0sImRldmljZSI6IlBvc3RtYW4ifQ._gEPrD2KsX1sFUwPmGSL0ZORSDRypwFd3u0Z-YhUowvE3iqDK0I_dpdkf_azCIUqs4JNpmj-zkKtmieRIz6afQ",
  "accepted_contract_term": true,
  "is_origin_pos": false
}
```

Comment: Existe algum motivo para não fazer o parse do json, e acessar os valores via `get` utilizando uma linguagem de programação?

Comment: @Danizavtz,obrigado pela resposta. Foi sugerido utilizar o json, contudo, segundo o fórum do Zabbix, os cenários web não suportam. Deste modo estou insistindo com o regex.

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo a ideia de ter os dois retornos em um mesmo regex, uma saída seria essa:

```
/"token_type":.?"(.*?)",|"access_token":.?"(.*?)",/g
```

Onde no Grupo 1, ele retorna o que está dentro do primeiro parênteses e no Grupo 2, do segundo.

[image: bearer]

[image: access_token]

Em Javascript, essa seria uma forma:

```js
const zabbix = `{
   "token_type": "bearer",
   "refresh_token": "MjUwMDAwMTJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIzNTMxMzI1MDAwMDE2NiIsImlhdCI6MTYxMjUzMjE2NSwibmJmIjoxNjEyNTMyMTY1LCJleHAiOjE2MTI1MzU3NjUsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6Im1vYmlsZUZpcnN0RGF0YSIsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6IjM1MzEzMjUwMDAwMTY2IiwiaW5zdGl0dXRpb24iOiIwMDAwMDAwMyIsImVzdGFibGleyJ0eXAiOijpbIjg5NDUwNDIzIl0sImRldmljZSI6IlBvc3RtYW4iLCJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsIm9yaWdpbl9wb3MiOmZhbHNlfQ.CEwEPwRXNN0OrcYk7rc2FFzPwMGPhOKnjUUfuR97bN7hfmwEMp_dQQ4mLRod4xuv32xlEFLPvmxtiM-9IiA53w",
   "refresh_expires_in": 3600,
   "expires_in": 900,
   "access_token": "osjjjjsssjJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIzNTMxMzI1MDAwMDE2NiIsImlhdCI6MTYxMjUzMjE2NSwibmJmIjoxNjEyNTMyMTY1LCJleHAiOjE2MTI1MzMwNjUsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6Im1vYmlsZUZpcnN0RGF0YSIsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6IjM1MzEzMjeyJ0eXAiOiIiwiaW5zdGl0dXRpb24iOiIwMDAwMDAwMyIsImVzdGFibGlzaG1lbnRzIjpbIjg5NDUwNDIzIl0sImRldmljZSI6IlBvc3RtYW4ifQ._gEPrD2KsX1sFUwPmGSL0ZORSDRypwFd3u0Z-YhUowvE3iqDK0I_dpdkf_azCIUqs4JNpmj-zkKtmieRIz6afQ",
   "accepted_contract_term": true,
   "is_origin_pos": false
}`;

const regex = /"token_type":.?"(.*?)",|"access_token":.?"(.*?)",/g;

// Test
const token_type = regex.exec(zabbix)[1];
const access_token = regex.exec(zabbix)[2];

console.log(token_type, access_token);
```